# Comparing two lists of names

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a short **Windows Presentation Foundation** application in **C#** to compare two lists in different formats and output the users that are common to them.

**Right now I am taking each list from the user via a textbox.**

Now I am a little confused on how I can compare the two different textboxes and output the common names. If the data was in an array of some sort I could have used:

```
var name = string.Split('(')[0].Trim()
```

But since I decided to use textboxes, I am unsure of how to proceed with this. For example, consider the following two input lists and the expected output:

**First List:**

```
Jacqueline Beaurivage (loh Da road); 
Bon Van Daht (fary goal lim)
Bon Jobi (ting wei)
Ting Wan (dehtee road);
```

**Second List:**

```
Jacqueline Beaurivage
Bon Van Daht
```

**Expected output:**

```
Jacqueline Beaurivage
Bon Van Daht
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var commonNames = firstList
                    .Select(m => m.Split('(')[0].Trim())
                    .Intersect(secondList);
```

with TextBoxes, as pointed by Austin Salonen

```
var firstList = textBox1.Text.Select(m => m.Split(Environment.NewLine));

var secondList = textBox2.Text.Select(m => m.Split(Environment.NewLine));

resultTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                           firstList
                             .Select(m => m.Split('(')[0].Trim())
                             .Intersect(secondList));
```

Comment: I get this error when I add your code: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' could be found.

Comment: @Harmond. Sorry, but you're asking for Lists. You mean this is the Text of a TextBox ?

Comment: Yes. This is the input in the textbox. Two text boxes receive each list as their input. I know it is easy to misinterpret because of lists in C# but this input is it textbox.

Comment: @Harmond and you can't compare the lists instead of input ? Please give some code, this looks rather unclear...

Comment: I don't know if I remember corrently but aren't lists fixed in the sense that the user chooses users form them where as here the user can paste text into the textbox and get the comparison. For my case the user pastes the text into the textbox...I can probably write some code to take the textbox input and convert it to a list to utilize your code...But if there is a different way then that is probably better.

Comment: @Harmond The `Text` property of each TextBox returns a string, which can be treated as a list of characters, to which you *can* apply the `Select` method. Give that a try.

Comment: `var firstList = firstListTextBox.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus  Thank you guys. I get some errors but I can work on debugging to make it work but you've given me it all pretty much! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out!